# Where tomcat.conf is located?

Tags: java, ubuntu, tomcat6

I can't find my `tomcat.conf`, I have looked in `/etc/tomcat6`, but it's not there, nor is it in `/usr/share/tomcat6`.

Where can I find the `tomcat.conf` in Linux Ubuntu?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no means of a `tomcat.conf` file in a default and plain vanilla Tomcat installation. You however can find several configuration files in the `/conf` folder. Details/manuals about those can be found at the [Apache Tomcat Configuration Reference](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/index.html).

Hope this helps.

Comment: There is a tomcat5.conf in /etc/tomcat5/tomcat5.conf.

Answer (score 7):

Try:

```
sudo updatedb
locate tomcat.conf | less
```

Answer (score 5):

`tomcat.conf` is a file that the RedHat RPM package of Tomcat installs. See [here](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/17128350/dir/other/com/tomcat7-7.0.22-1.jpp6.noarch.rpm.html). It's actually a nice way of managing tomcat config stuff in a file rather than environment variables.

Comment: That was my point. Tomcat.conf is a file that I've only seen installed by  the RedHat RPM package. He must have been reading a tutorial that was based on RedHat and thus mentioned to update tomcat.conf. On Ubuntu, he'll have to configure it a different way.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure what you're looking for but here is the filelist of the package *tomcat6* on *karmic*:

```
/etc/cron.daily/tomcat6
/etc/default/tomcat6
/etc/init.d/tomcat6
/etc/tomcat6/catalina.properties
/etc/tomcat6/context.xml
/etc/tomcat6/logging.properties
/etc/tomcat6/policy.d/01system.policy
/etc/tomcat6/policy.d/02debian.policy
/etc/tomcat6/policy.d/03catalina.policy
/etc/tomcat6/policy.d/04webapps.policy
/etc/tomcat6/policy.d/50local.policy
/etc/tomcat6/server.xml
/etc/tomcat6/tomcat-users.xml
/etc/tomcat6/web.xml
/usr/share/doc/tomcat6/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/tomcat6/copyright
/usr/share/tomcat6/webapps/default_root/META-INF/context.xml
/usr/share/tomcat6/webapps/default_root/index.html
/var/lib/tomcat6/conf
/var/lib/tomcat6/logs
/var/lib/tomcat6/work
```

Comment: I am looking at this (http://wiki.foochal.org/index.php/CruiseControl_FAQ) tutorial and it told me to 

Configure tomcat.conf to specify dashboard-config.xml 

So that was my problem.. thanks anyways...

Comment: I've checked the tutorial and have no idea of what *"Configure tomcat.conf to specify dashboard-config.xml"* could mean. This doesn't make any sense...

Comment: I googled a bit and it *look like* that there's a `tomcat.conf` in Apache JK connector. At any way, hkshambesh, whenever having startup problems with a particular product, in the future please refer the vendor-supplied documentation instead of some blogs/sites of which you never know if they are correct. Always use vendor-supplied docs.

Comment: @BalusC Oh, indeed, there are references to `tomcat.conf` in the JK connector documentation. I don't think this is what the tutorial refers to though and agree with your comment.

Answer (score 1):

You may check that by:

```
$ dpkg -L tomcat6 tomcat6-common | grep tomcat.conf
```

Answer (score 1):

The tomcat-users.xml file is located in the Tomcat install directory of the etc directory.

For instance. From root:

```
cd /etc/tomcat(ENTER-YOUR-TOMCAT-VERSION-HERE)/tomcat-users.xml
```

In my system I have Tomcat7 installed so my path was"

```
/etc/tomcat7/tomcat-users.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are running Docker container based on alpine all the configuration you can find inside conf.

```
/usr/local/tomcat/conf
```