# Tomcat 7 fails to start due to absence of jmxremote.access file while JMX authentication is disabled

Tags: java, tomcat, jmx

My tomcat 7 (hosting at amazon-eu, java 1.7.0_51) fails to start with the following exception:

```
SEVERE: Catalina.start:org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:684)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:456)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: jmxremote.access (No such file or directory)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer.start(RMIConnectorServer.java:372)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.JmxRemoteLifecycleListener.createServer(JmxRemoteLifecycleListener.java:304)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.JmxRemoteLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent(JmxRemoteLifecycleListener.java:258)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:402)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:347)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:725)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 7 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: jmxremote.access (No such file or directory)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:137)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:96)
        at com.sun.jmx.remote.security.MBeanServerFileAccessController.propertiesFromFile(MBeanServerFileAccessController.java:294)
        at com.sun.jmx.remote.security.MBeanServerFileAccessController.<init>(MBeanServerFileAccessController.java:133)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer.start(RMIConnectorServer.java:370)
        ... 15 more
```

JMX is enabled, because I have the following line in /usr/share/tomcat7/conf/tomcat7.conf:

```
$CATALINA_OPTS=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=ec2-<ip>.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
```

and the following one in /usr/share/tomcat7/conf/server.xml:

```
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.JmxRemoteLifecycleListener"
           rmiRegistryPortPlatform="9998" rmiServerPortPlatform="9998"/>
```

If I comment both these lines, everything is fine.

The question is: why jmxremote.access is required while "authenticate" was set to false.

Comment: Vitaly, have any of the answers work for you? Care to accept as correct if they did?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're absolutely right, if you set `com.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false` you shouldn't need the `jmxremote.access` file, I believe the problem is that the JMX parameters aren't getting picked up by tomcat, for what I know, `tomcat7.conf` isn't a standard config file for tomcat ([check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1875162/where-is-tomcat-conf-in-ubuntu)), try adding them instead to  `/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/catalina.sh`, like this:

```
CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=ec2-<ip>.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false"
```

fore more info on how to configure tomcat [check this](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/RUNNING.txt), you'll see some more doc in the header of `catalina.sh`.

Answer (score 0):

Try enclosing the command-line parameters in double quotes, e.g.:

```
$CATALINA_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=ec2-<ip>.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false"
```

My guess is that it's only taking the first paramter into account because of the missing quotes.